mvn javafx:jlink fails to build because a dependency is automatic
I am trying to use jlink to package a JavaFX application, and I am getting the following error when running mvn javafx:jlink or mvn clean javafx:jlink
Error: automatic module cannot be used with jlink: com.github.oshi from file:///home/me/.m2/repository/com/github/oshi/oshi-core/6.6.2/oshi-core-6.6.2.jar


I have added moditect to my pom, because I read on a different thread that the issue is that it doesn't have a module-info file, but I am still getting this error. Here is what I have for moditect. I also want to say that idk what I'm doing with the --multi-release=21 arg, but I get other errors if I don't have it.
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.moditect</groupId>
   <artifactId>moditect-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
   <executions>
      <execution>
         <id>generate-module-info</id>
         <phase>generate-sources</phase>
         <goals>
            <goal>generate-module-info</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
            <modules>
               <module>
                  <artifact>
                     <groupId>com.github.oshi</groupId>
                     <artifactId>oshi-core</artifactId>
                     <version>${oshi.version}</version>
                  </artifact>
               </module>
            </modules>
            <jdepsExtraArgs>
               <arg>--upgrade-module-path=...</arg>
               <arg>--multi-release=21</arg>
            </jdepsExtraArgs>
         </configuration>
      </execution>
   </executions>
</plugin>

